# Is there a way to allow certain numbers to be called from a locked phone?

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, contacts, emergency-calls

When I got my first cell phone I was told to put a "In case of an emergency call  XXX" at the top of my list of phone numbers.  While I haven't ever benefited directly from that, I have benefited from similar emergency preparedness advice.  My old phone finally made the trip to electronics heaven (RIP dear RAZR) and I moved over to a Verizon Android phone (Samsung Stratosphere - with Gingerbread 2.3.5). I really like that I can "lock" this phone to prevent someone else from using it in malicious ways, but I would really like a method for someone to be able to determine who my emergency contacts are, and ideally contact those people, if I'm ever incapacitated.

When I saw the "Emergency Call" button I thought that might be the functionality I was looking for, but it isn't - ( [What is an "Emergency Call," and can I  set number for it?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/7731/what-is-an-emergency-call-and-can-i-set-number-for-it) )

Is there any way to have two or three people and their contact info accessible without unlocking the phone?

***Clarifying edit***: Maybe I'm being picky, but I'd also like to have my emergency contacts actually able to be contacted, i.e., someone could pick up my phone - without knowing the lock code - and actually be able to *call* my emergency contacts.

Comment: I'd still go with ID and maybe a card with contacts on it in your wallet ;)

Answer (score 4):

Matthew's comment seems most practical ...

But you can try [Contact Owner](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.appengine.paranoid_android.lost); that displays info for one contact on your lock screen.   I use it; it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

There are quite many [ICE (In Case of Emergency)](https://market.android.com/search?q=in%20case%20of%20emergency&so=1&c=apps) apps on the market; these apps displays your contact information in your lock screen.