# How to create an "if found" wallpaper for Android?

Tags: lock-screens, lost-phone, wallpaper

[This is where I saw the terminology "if found wallpaper"](https://www.hanselman.com/blog/ten-things-to-do-to-secure-an-important-persons-computer-or-even-ashtons-or-a-kardashians).

> **Make an "If Found" Wallpaper**
>
> However, if you do use a password or pin and lock your phone by default, be sure to update your wallpaper to include contact info.

Basically, since we're all locking our phones, you want a wallpaper that contains contact information, in case it's lost. Is there such a wallpaper for Android?

Comment: It's a pity that the built-in lock screens don't have a way to do this. Blackberrys have had a setting for years that allows you to set an "Owner Name" and "Owner Info" text that shows up when the device is locked. As my Blackberries have always been company devices, I just have my initials and an if found ring company switchboard text. The company also puts a sticker on the inside of the battery compartment door with a serial number and the company switchboard number.

Comment: Well, they DID add this in on Honeycomb. My tablet (Acer Iconia a500) has it built in on the lock screen. Did they cross-port this to ICS? I don't have it yet.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Android OS versions 3.x and above (Honeycomb, Ice Cream Sandwich) actually have a setting that allows you to specify "Owner info" text that will show up when the device is locked.

There are also many 3rd-party locks-screen replacement apps that allow for much greater configuration flexibility than the stock one, including the ability to specify any text on the locks-screen.

For the "unlocked" state, you can always modify an image to include the "if found..." text, copy it onto the device's SD Card (or internal storage area), and set that as the wallpaper.  You can use one of the myriad of free image editing software (e.g. [Paint.NET](https://www.getpaint.net/)) to add the text.

Comment: CyanogenMod also has it too (or it used to in CM6).

Comment: The setting is missing from the front-end on CM7.x, but if you edit the settings database manually and add the text, it will show up ;)

Comment: Makes me long even more for Galaxy Nexus' release on AT&T! meantime, can you guys explain how to back-end this in in CM7? I tried googling, but I only found something that looked like it was specific to Verizon phones.

Comment: @eidylon: The exact statements you need to execute are here: http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?p=11132463#post11132463

Comment: @BryanDenny: And also the toggle to turn it on: http://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=11144146&postcount=13532

Answer (score 1):

To expand on [Chahk's answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/17791/44325): go to the **Settings** app, and from the **Personal** section, choose **Security** (on a Samsung phone, choose **Lock screen** instead). Then tap **Owner info**, and enter your name, room number, phone number (though not of the same phone, obviously), or whatever.