# Can I hide the time on the Cyanogenmod 7 Lockscreen?

Tags: cyanogenmod, lock-screens, customization, clock

I've flashed CM7 onto my phone, and am wondering if there is a way to hide the clock. The only way I see is the `Widget Layout` setting to `Default/Hidden/Centered`. But this hides ALL text on the lock screen, I want to hide **ONLY** the clock (because it is in the statusbar anyway), and NOT hide the next alarm, next calendar appointment, battery level, etc.

Or, as an alternative, if there is someway to make the font for the clock a LOT smaller.

The reason I want to do this, is because I am using [Contact Owner](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.appengine.paranoid_android.lost) to display lost phone text on the lock screen, but with that giant clock up top, it pushes the owner info underneath/behind the unlock controls.

Also, setting the `Widget Layout` to hidden hides the owner info as well, which kinda defeats the purpose.

**UPDATE:** With a little help from [this question](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/17778/whats-a-good-if-found-wallpaper-for-android/17791#17791), I'm using Cyanogenmod's own owner info ability, but it still suffers from the same problem.

BTW, I'm running on a Galaxy S Captivate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I didn't find a way to hide it; but switched to using WidgetLocker for my lock screen and just disabled CM's.