# How do I make "Emergency Call" harder to hit? I keep pocket calling 911!

Tags: lock-screens, emergency-calls

I have a Samsung Captivate Glide phone running 4.0.4 on the AT&T network.

Unfortunately, I have pocket called 911 at least four times.  To call 911 on my phone you have to:

1. Activate the lock screen
2. Swipe near the bottom of the screen on "Emergency Call"
3. Press on the screen

I think that this is how it happens:

1. I unplug the phone from the charger (which wakes the phone up from sleep and shows the lock screen)
2. I slide the phone into my pocket without looking at it (which does the swipe)
3. The button gets pressed in my pocket

How can I stop this from happening?    I'm hoping for something like an app that replaces the lock screen, or a setting to change it from a single button press to actually dialing 9-1-1.

For clarification, I have not rooted this phone.

Comment: There are lots of lockscreen replacements, like [Go Locker](http://www.appbrain.com/app/go-locker/com.jiubang.goscreenlock), that might help. Unfortunately, I don't know if this is a sure-fire solution for you - and I don't know how to disable that feature on your default lockscreen.

Comment: Do you have root?

Comment: I tried Go Locker, but it replaced my home screen as well as my lock screen.  I didn't want to have to reconfigure all my widgets and shortcuts on the home screen, so I uninstalled it.

Comment: I always turn the screen back off before putting it in my pocket. If you could get into this habit, it would solve your problem I think.

Comment: A simple workaround in the below post... it worked for me.

http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/7731/what-is-an-emergency-call-and-can-i-set-number-for-it/56045#56045

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added several additional emergency contacts [using these instructions](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/56045/30767).

Now 911 is just one of several numbers that can be called from the emergency call screen.   I made most of the numbers "dummy" numbers that don't actually connect.   While this probably won't prevent all emergency pocket calls, at least 911 shouldn't be a common selection any longer.

Answer (score 1):

Just search for [lockscreen](https://play.google.com/store/search?q=lockscreen&c=apps) in the Google Play Store. There are many lockscreen replacers available. I think [Start](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.celltick.lockscreen) might be a good one to start with.

Make sure to read the instructions on these apps. Some require other apps like GO Locker (requires GO Launcher) to be installed first.